# Secure User Image Upload Capabilities in PHP

Tags: php, security, image, file-upload, upload

I'm implementing a user-based image uploading tool for my website.  The system should allow any users to upload JPEG and PNG files only.   I'm, of course, worried about security and so I'm wondering how the many smarter people than myself feel about the following checks for allowing uploads:

1) First white list the allowable file extensions in PHP to allow only PNG, png, jpg, JPG and JPEG.  Retrieve the user's file's extension via a function such as:

```
return end(explode(".", $filename));
```

This should help disallow the user from uploading something malicious like .png.php.  If this passes, move to step 2.

2) Run the php function getimageize() on the TMP file. Via something like:

```
getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
```

If this does not return false, proceed.

3) Ensure a .htaccess file is placed within the uploads directory so that any files within this directory cannot parse PHP files:

```
php_admin_value engine Off
```

4) Rename the user's file to something pre-determined. I.E.

```
$filename = 'some_pre_determined_unique_value' . $the_file_extension;
```

This will also help prevent SQL injection as the filename will be the only user-determined variable in any queries used.

If I perform the above, how vulnerable for attack am I still?  Before accepting a file I should hopefully have 1) only allowed jpgs and pngs, 2) Verified that PHP says it's a valid image, 3) disabled the directory the images are in from executing .php files and 4) renamed the users file to something unique.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you use strip_tags on an image file to remove PHP tags?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Regarding file names, random names are definitely a good idea and take away a lot of headaches.

If you want to make totally sure the content is clean, consider using GD or ImageMagick to copy the incoming image 1:1 into a new, empty one.

That will slightly diminish image quality because content gets compressed twice, but it will remove any EXIF information present in the original image. Users are often not even aware how much info gets put into the Metadata section of JPG files! Camera info, position, times, software used... It's good policy  for sites that host images to remove that info for the user.

Also, copying the image will probably get rid of most exploits that use faulty image data to cause overflows in the viewer software, and inject malicious code. Such manipulated images will probably simply turn out unreadable for GD.

Comment: Great answer. I'll just add that as an additional defence, serve the images from a throw-away domain other than the domain where you set cookies. That way, even the image somehow has executable client side code, browser's same origin policy will prevent much harm.

Comment: @sri great idea, haven't thought of that!

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan how to setup a throw away domain for images..any reference..for your answer

Comment: @sid - Buy another domain and serve images from that domain. For example, google serves user content from the domain googleusercontent.com.

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan thanks..how will i ensure that domain is cookieless and when uploading photos will i have to save images in that domain?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your number 2), don't just check for `FALSE`. getimagesize will also return the mime type of the image. This is by far a more secure way to check proper image type than looking at the mime type the client supplies:

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
if ($info === FALSE) {
    die("Couldn't read image");
}
if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG)) {
    die("Not a JPEG or PNG");
}
```

Comment: it's possible for a file to be valid gif and contain php code at the same time. thus getimagesize() won't give much of real protection.

Comment: @Andre: Anything that can contain text can contain PHP code. At least with images the PHP won't get executed unless the webserver's configuration is incredibly bad.

Comment: I usually recode image to bmp and back to original extension using imagick - this get's rid of any malicious code in that image file.

Answer (score 1):

All the checks seem good, number 3 in particular. If performance is not an issue, or you are doing this in the background, you could try accessing the image using GD and seeing if it is indeed an image and not just a bunch of crap that someone is trying to fill your server with.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning No. 2, I read on php.net ([documentation of the function getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) ):

> Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.