# What is a good practice for uploading images and displaying them?

Tags: php

I want to use an iframe to upload images and display them as a kind of preview next to the form without having to reload the page.  What is the best way to do this.  I have other form data, such as title and content, if that matter.  The problem i run into is i dont want to have to save the file to the server to have to display it. Is there a way i can get around saving it?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644138/secure-user-image-upload-capabilities-in-php and http://nullcandy.com/php-image-upload-security-how-not-to-do-it/ and https://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+image+uploading+security&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

Comment: **i dont want to have to save the file to the server**  where do you want to save ??